# Camada de introdução no site (float div)

Tags: css

Preciso de encontrar uma solução em que abra uma camada para colocar publicidade que se feche de forma automática caso o utilizador não faça nada.

Existe algum script que possam recomendar?

Será que me podem ajudar com essa questão?

Comment: Esta pergunta parece ser descontextualizada porque não apresenta nenhum esforço de pesquisa ou tentativas anteriores.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode utilizar a função `setTimeout`. Veja um exemplo:

```js
jQuery(function(){
  
  var itv = window.setTimeout(function(){
    
    jQuery("div.publicidade").fadeOut("fast", function(){ //ocultando a div da pagina com um efeito de fade
      jQuery("div.publicidade").remove(); //eliminando a div
      window.clearInterval(itv);
    });
    
  }, 3000); // delay de 3 segundos para executar a ação
  
});
```

```css
div.publicidade{position:absolute; width: 200px; height: 200px; background: #efefef; border: 1px solid #ccc; top:100px; left: 100px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="publicidade"></div>
```